# Can multiple Spring sessions be backed by same redis instance?

Tags: spring-session, spring-data-redis

We have a couple of web applications written on Java Spring, we are using `spring-data-redis` and `@EnableRedisHttpSession`. I was wondering what are the spring session internals. Would it check redis database for duplicate session keys before creating a new session?

I looked at spring documentation and also did a google search but couldn't get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution after going through spring session project's github issues. Answer provided by @Avnish doesn't work because in cluster configuration redis does not provide databases, there is just a single database `0` and `SELECT` commands are not supported.

`spring-session@1.1.0.RELEASE` solves this issue by providing session namespaces. If you are using [`@EnableRedisHttpSession`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisHttpSession.html) annotation, you can add [`redisNamespace`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisHttpSession.html#redisNamespace--) property to it. Or you can add the key in `spring.session.redis.namespace` property in your `.properties` or `.yml` file.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that setting spring.session.redis.namespace in application.yml works? I cannot seem to get this set dynamically at runtime, which I need.

Answer (score 1):

As far as as spring-session is concerned, it'll assume that another application is part of the cluster and will try to reuse existing session if found for given id, although very unlikely that two different applications will generate same session ids considering it's generated via random UUID. Following are the options that you can go with to safe guard yourself anyway.

If you are using spring boot, use different value of `spring.redis.database` property for each of your application (details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), search for "**# REDIS**")

If you are using spring-data-redis directly then you should be setting this value directly in the JedisConnectionFactory bean that you are using in your application. For XML configuration, following would do:

```
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
  <property name="database" value="1" />
</beans>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: redis `database`s are not available in cluster mode.